# Runtime error in xmemory0() file in vc using opencv in visual studio

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015

I am using OpenCV and MS Visual Studio to simply detect Surf Features in a sample image. It compiles and build all fine but gives a runtime error in xmemory0() file located in:

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xmemory0

The debugger breaks in the following block in xmemory0():

```
 #ifdef _DEBUG
    // If the following asserts, it likely means that we are performing
    // an aligned delete on memory coming from an unaligned allocation.
    _SCL_SECURE_ALWAYS_VALIDATE(
        reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t *>(_Ptr_ptr)[-1] ==
            _BIG_ALLOCATION_SENTINEL);#endif /* _DEBUG */
```

I just cant seem to understand the problem. Any thought would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try with "Run-Time Error Checks" compiler option. This may give some clue. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wtf2dfz.aspx

Comment: Are you using OpenCV x86 with a x64 project? Are you using opencv debug libs in release? Or viceversa?

Comment: @Miki yes the project and the library included, both are of x64 architecture

Comment: did you mange to solve this problem?

Comment: After hard work i solve it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54137173/10895122
i wish that help you.