# run error xmemory() with function findchessboardcorners()?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, visual-studio-2013

I am using OpenCV and MS Visual Studio 2013 to simply detect chessboard. It compiles and build all fine but gives a runtime error in `xmemory0()` file located in:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xmemory0
```

I just cant seem to understand the problem. Any thought would be appreciated.

The debugger breaks in `xmemory0()`, I thought that the problem in `findChessboardCorners()` function and library opencv-core2410. I tried same function with vs2010 and it works, but I need to do it with vs2013.

Comment: When the debugger breaks, look at the call stack. That's the list of calls that led to the break. See who's calling `xmemory0()`, and who's calling that, etc., until you get into your code. That's where the problem is showing up.

Comment: I know that problem in findChessboardCorners() function

Answer (score 0):

After hard work i found that i must determine the size of cv::vector variables before use it, for example:

```
cv::vector<Point2f> corners;
corners.resize(54);
bool patternfound = findChessboardCorners(gray, patternsize, corners,CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK | CV_CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE);
```

I didn't need to resize vector in vs2010 but just in vs2013.